# Trying to send a picture with text to Instagram stories but com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY does nothing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, instagram-story

I have read a lot of information on various sites, but not a single method works. There are also a lot of old solutions on the sites that don't work either. Here is my code:

```
Uri stickerAssetUri =  Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/schooly-47238.appspot.com/o/miners%2Ffimw.png?alt=media&token=9798e9ea-15a0-4ef2-869b-63ce4dc95b78");
String sourceApplication = "com.egormoroz.schooly";

Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
intent.putExtra("source_application", sourceApplication);

intent.setType("image/зтп");
intent.putExtra("interactive_asset_uri", stickerAssetUri);
intent.putExtra("top_background_color", "#33FF33");
intent.putExtra("bottom_background_color", "#FF00FF");


Activity activity = getActivity();
activity.grantUriPermission(
        "com.instagram.android", stickerAssetUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
if (activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

When this part of the code is triggered, nothing happens to the application. It remains on the same screen.

Comment: I think you should change intent.setType("image/зтп") to intent.setType("image/*")

Answer (score 0):

Based on official documentation from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/.

You can change this

```
intent.setType("image/зтп");
```

to

```
intent.setType("image/*");
```

or

```
intent.setType(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `sourceApplication` should be your Facebook App ID, not your package name.